# How to run sikuli script through Python script

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I want to run sikulixIDE-1.1.3 generated script through Python IDLE but don't know how to add in Python script.

I have generated file sikuli_script.sikuli using sikuliXIDE-1.1.3.
Through Python IDLE, I opened application but the next step is I want to call this sikuli script but don't know the way to add it.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application().start(r"C:/Program Files/Keysight/ADS2020/bin/ads.exe")
import os
>>> os.popen('python C:/Users/aakotkar/Desktop/Agile/GUI_Automation/Sikuli_script.sikuli/Sikuli_script.py')
<os._wrap_close object at 0x000001D32063F780>
```

It should run sikuli script but I know I am calling in wrong way. Any help?

Comment: Finally got success by calling sikuli through bat script

Comment: import pywinauto
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:/Program Files/Keysight/ADS2020/bin/ads.exe")
import time
time.sleep(45)
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:/Users/aakotkar/Desktop/Agile/GUI_Automation/sikuli_run.bat", shell=True)